# Нужна помощь с регулярным выражением - PHP

Tags: php

Получаю контент страницы через CURL и пропускаю через функцию `htmlspecialchars`. 
На выходе большой объем кода, поэтому укажу нужный участок:

```
<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/{domain}\/search.js?p=&query=Hlo9oDDbbm4{ch}&keywords=phone\"><\/script>
```

Код выше я помещаю в переменную `$text` и пытаюсь получить значение `Hlo9oDDbbm4`:

```
preg_match("/search.js?p=&query=(.*?){ch}&keywords=phone/",$text,$matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

но у меня ничего не выходит. Как правильно составить регулярное выражение?

Comment: `s?` в вашем выражение значит наличие или отсутствие буквы `s`. Сам вопросительный знак при этом в строке не ожидается. Надо поставить перед ним обратную косую, что бы он означал сам себя. Но т.к. у вас строка в двойных кавычках, то вам надо удвоить обратную косую т.е. `\\.js\\?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли заэкранировать `.` и `?` Просто немного поправьте паттерн `search.js?p=&query=(.*?){ch}&keywords=phone`

```
preg_match("/search\\.js\\?p=&query=(.*?){ch}&keywords=phone/",$text,$matches);
```

Comment: минус так как парсить html надо через dom дерево а не регуляркой.

Comment: @Venta, Благодарю! Ваш ответ помог. ;)

Answer (score 1):

И так вы получаете контент страницы через `curl`, зачем вам всё экранировать `htmlspecialchars` это не к чему. Далее загружаете переменую в парсер расмотрим на примере `simple_html_dom`

```
$html = str_get_html($content);
foreach($html->find('script') as $element) {
     $src = $element->src;
     if(strpos($src,'/search.js') {
        parse_string($src);
        echo $query;// искомое значение
     }
}
```

Так правильнее.

Comment: Плюс, потому что чему то научился, правда не совсем понятно, что делать, если `search.js` подключается несколько раз

Comment: @Venta Ну так что будет с исользованием регулярки? Плюс регулярка перебирает посимвольно строку находит совпадение и далее ищет следующее вхождение и так несколько раз в зависимости от регулярного выражения...